# How to change property of field while redirecting to same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a  js page in my react app where I have one calendar div and I'm showing one popup card with one close button.

If I click that button then it should redirect to me to the same page with calendar div open.

I'm using `window.history.back()` to redirect to the same page only and it's working but how can I make that div display.

Answer (score 0):

What you would normally do is, after doing:

 `window.history.back()`, you do something like
`document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-div')[0].classList.add('show');`

This would add a `.show` class to the `calendar-div` element. If you're using a third party plugin, this would be explained in their docs, but for this instance, you would then add something like this to your css

```
.calendar-div{
   opacity:0; // let us say you are using this to introduce the div in the redirect
}
.calendar-div.active{
   opacity:1;
}
```

With the minimalist question, this is what I can deduce as the suitable answer, you can update your question or add a comment in my answer.